# iPhone4 Core Data how to insert a new object with section number?

Tags: core-data, ios5, nsfetchedresultscontroller, iphone-4, nsindexpath

I'm trying to insert new objects into my core data structure and have them know which section they belong to.

Here's my insert method, I need to add a certain section to the new record.

```
-(void)insertNewReminderWithSequenceNumber:(int)sequenceNumber
{
    // Create a new instance of the entity managed by the fetched results controller.
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.remindersController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.remindersController fetchRequest] entity];
    Reminder *newManagedObject = (Reminder*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
    newManagedObject.sequenceNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sequenceNumber];

}
```

Here's my retrieve method, note that I set the section to zero.

```
-(Reminder*)getReminderAtIndex:(int)index
{
    NSIndexPath* temp = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
    Reminder* reminder  = nil;
    @try {
       reminder= [self.remindersController objectAtIndexPath:temp];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception accessing event at index: %i", index);
        return nil;
    }
    @finally {

    }

    return reminder;
}
```

**How can I insert objects into core data to be able to retrieve them by indexPath containing both section number and row number?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the provided method `objectAtIndexPath`:

```
Reminder *reminder = (Reminder *) [self.fetchedResultsController 
   objectAtIndexPath];
```

This has nothing to do with how you insert the object into the managed object context. Rather, you will have to specify your sections with the `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter of your `NSFetchedResultsController`.